# How do I resolve 'DictReader' object is not subscriptable error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary

I'm trying to import a csv and then print results out as sentences using f-strings.

My csv look like this:

```
"MONTH(purchases.date)","total_revenue_per_month"
"1","264510"
"2","226199"
"3","247469"
"4","254352"
"5","281448"
"6","258480"
"7","260668"
"8","263922"
"9","127317"
```

and the code I'm trying to use is:

```
import csv

with open('total_revenue.csv') as csvfile:
    MonthlyRevenue = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=",", quotechar = '"')
    
for row in MonthlyRevenue:
    print (f"For the month {MonthlyRevenue['MONTH(purchases.date)']} the total revenue was {MonthlyRevenue['total_revenue_per_month']}.")
```

When I run the code I get TypeError: 'DictReader' object is not subscriptable.  What does this error mean?  How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to access keys from each `row`, not from the `DictReader` instance.

For instance, use

```
row['MONTH(purchases.date)']
```

rather than

```
MonthlyRevenue['MONTH(purchases.date)']
```

Iterating over the object `MonthlyRevenue` gives you each row as a `dict`. It's that dictionary that you can access as you want, such as in this [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) example.